# fgets() not waiting for input with no stdin overflow?

Tags: c, buffer, stdin, fgets, buffer-overflow

It is It's probably something simple but after a few hours of googleing and debugging I can not figure it out. Basically basically I want to get user input, then another function validates the input and returns either TRUE or FALSE if TRUE or FALSE if the input is well... accepted or not.

My my code is over multiple files so I will I'll only post the relevant section:

```
do {
   printf("Enter customers surname: ");
   fgets(userinput, sizeof(userinput), stdin);

} while (validCustData(datapos, userinput) != TRUE);
```

Debugging debugging: Using using code::blocks debugger it skips over the fgets() statement fgets() statement and tries to validate a NULL pointer NULL pointer causing a crash. I have tried fflush(stdin) and fflush(stdin) and my own readrestofinput() function readrestofinput() function that clears the buffers,. but nothing is working. Any any help please?

EDIT: I have it working now. `userinput` was `NULL`ed but now i fixed that I have a different error.

```
0 764746A7 msvcrt!fgets() (C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll:??) 
1 60758FC7 ?? () (??:??)
2 ?? ?? () (??:??)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In msvcrt!fgets () (C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll)
```

Comment: How was `userinput` declared?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is forbidden by the C specification. `userinput` should never be `NULL` since you need to pass a valid pointer to `fgets`, and `fgets` doesn't (in fact can't) change the pointer. You *should* check the return value from `fgets` which *may* be `NULL`. The `readrestofinput()` function would be interesting to see.

Comment: this is my readrestofline function. 
void readRestOfLine()
{
   int c;

   /* Read until the end of the line or end-of-file. */
   while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
      ;

   /* Clear the error and end-of-file flags. */
   clearerr(stdin);
}
the reason I know it's empty is cause when I call this function it asks for an input

Comment: `userinput` must be declared! E.g. `char userinput[512]=""`

Comment: OMG that was so simple..... can you post that as an answer so I can accept it and vote you up. thanks!

Comment: No compiler error? Do you have a function called `userinput`? You should enable warnings in your compiler (-Wall for gcc).

Comment: I am using -Wall -pedantic and -ansi